# Android ListView Row Text Change Dynamically

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView with BaseAdapter and I create this adapter in my main Activity. In my adapter constructor, I also have an String list that fills the TextViews in ListView rows in "getView" method. After that, according to user interaction, I want to change text of TextViews in ListView rows, but how could I manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update string or stirngs in your Adapter's "String list" and than call BaseAdapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

This will notify all listeners that data is changed and in your particular case will result in `ListView` re-fetching visible views from your Adapter. And your Adapter will return views with new updated strings.

Comment: If there are several views changing frequently, showing sensor data for example, is this still an acceptable method?